# Checking if SESSION value

Tags: php, session

I want to check session data. The value of $_SESSION['yatidak'] is 'Tidak', but i can't check the condition. Why? Please see the code

```
$yt = $_SESSION['yatidak'];
echo $yt;
// output : Tidak

if ($yt=='Tidak') {
    echo 'Tidak';
}else{
    echo 'Iya';
}
// output : Iya
```

Echo should be :

```
// TidakTidak
```

But the result is :

```
// TidakIYa
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe you're checking when the SESSION is not set and another time when it's set or something?

Comment: Instead of `echo $yt;`, try a `var_dump($yt);` so we can see what it gives.

Comment: cannot reproduce...that should work! try this to see yourself `if($_SESSION['yatidak'] && $_SESSION['yatidak']==='Tidak') {echo 'tidak'}else{echo 'me'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual process is you have to do is,

```
session_start(); //at the very first line of the page
//Check the session value direct to the string and use trim if some white spaces are there should be removed and also use `===` which match type and data both
if (trim($_SESSION['yatidak']) === "Tidak") { 
    echo 'Tidak';
}else{
    echo 'Iya';
}
// output sould be: Tidak
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
if ( ($yt = $_SESSION['yatidak']) == 'Tidak') {
    echo 'Tidak';
}else{
    echo 'Iya';
}
```

If that works, for adaptation of your code, make sure the $_SESSION['yatidak'] is not modified between the assignation and the verification.